# cv::findcontours causes a program crash

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get contours from my frame and this is what I have done:

```
 cv::Mat frame,helpframe,yframe,frame32f;
 Videocapture cap(1); 
.......
while(waitkey()){
cv::Mat result = cv::Mat::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
frame.convertTo(frame32f,CV_32FC3);
for ( int w = 0; w< 10;w ++){
            result += frame32f;
        }   
         //Average the frame values.
        result *= (1.0/10);
        result /= 255.0f;
cvtColor(result,yframe,CV_RGB2YCrCb); // converting to Ycbcr///// the code work fine when I use frame instead of result 
extractChannel(yframe,helpframe,0); //extracting the Y channel
cv::minMaxLoc(helpframe,&minValue,&maxValue,&min,&max);
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
cv::findContours(helpframe, contours,CV_RETR_LIST /*CV_RETR_EXTERNAL*/, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

....................................................

the program crashs at `findcontours`, and I debbug I get this error message:

> > OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats ([Start]FindContours
> >     support only 8uC1 and 32sC1 images) in unknown function, file ......\src\openc
> >     v\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp, line 196

@Niko thanks for help I think that I have to convert helpframe to another type.
when I use   **result** I get for 
     helpframe.type()       => 5 
 and with **frame**  I get   0
I don't know what does it mean ? but I'll try to find a way to convert helpframe.

after converting helpframe with :
     helpframe.convertTo(helpframe2,CV_8U)

I get nothing  helpframe2 is = 0 ?? and when I try the same with frame instead of resultframe the conversion works  ??

Any idea how I should change the helpframe type because I use result instead of frame?

Comment: That "extractChannel" function is not part of OpenCV, is it?

Comment: Can you check what `helpframe.channels()` reports right before `findContours`?

Comment: helpframe.channels() is 1, and I don't think this it the problem because when  I check it  by use frame instead of result it stay 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to reduce the image to a binary image before you can identify contours. This can be done by, e.g., applying some kind of edge detection algorithm or by simple thresholding:

```
// Binarize the image
cv::threshold(helpframe, helpframe, 50, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

// Convert from 32F to 8U
cv::Mat helpframe2;
helpframe.convertTo(helpframe2, CV_8U);

cv::findContours(helpframe2, ...);
```

Comment: @Engine Added conversion to unsigned char (which should be accepted by findContours).

Comment: I don't get what do you mean

Comment: Both the (extensive) [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) and the error message state that "findContours" requires a singel channel 8-bit input image. You've already managed to extract a single channel but what is missing is the conversion to CV_8UC1. This can by achieved by doing `helpframe.convertTo(helpframe2, CV_8U);` - what I meant was that I've added the appropriate code to my example above.